# Celery + Django on Windows: debugging asynchronous tasks

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, pdb

With Django 1.8 I used `Django-celery` to run asynchronous tasks and I was able to debug them in my IDE (either PyCharm or Eclipse+PyDev) just launching "python celery worker" in debug mode.

`Django-celery` doesn't support Django 2.2, so I have to run pure celery.exe.
Celery docs say that I have to add `pdb` to my code and run debug via console.

How can I debug these tasks as I did before, adding breakpoints dynamically from my IDE?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True` setting in you development env. If this is True, all tasks will be executed locally without sending it to a queue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [celery.contrib.rdb](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/debugging.html), an extension of pdb.

```
from celery.contrib import rdb
from celery.task import task

@task
def add(x,y):
    result=× + y
    rdb.set_trace()  #set breakpoint
    return x+y
```

Open next terminal and type

```
telnet localhost 6900
```

Now you are in debug mode.

Comment: Yes, but this will force me to know in advance where to put breakpoints. Is it possible to add them dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Telnet solution doesn't work for me.
But I was able to debug my tasks with `pdb`.

Add breakpoint: `pdb.set_trace()`.

Then just run worker with `-l warning`, it will prevent printing of excessive info.